# shell expanding rename command backreferences

Tags: bash, shell, perl, rename, command-substitution

When I'm using group matched pattern in `rename` command and use their back references in replacement part and I also want to have command substitution expansion as well within my `rename` command and using double quotes to expand, but shell also considering back references as parameters though and that cause problem renaming. How can I avoid this?

```
rename "s:(.*)$(date +"%Y%m%d"):$1$(date -d "+1day" +"%Y%m%d"):" *
```

Also I tried seperate command substitution expansion part but didn't luck, it just printing extra quotes around `$(date -d "+1day" +"%Y%m%d")`.

```
rename 's:(.*)'"$(date +"%Y%m%d")"':$1'"'"$(date -d "+1day" +"%Y%m%d")"'"':' *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape `$` in `$1`:

```
rename "s:(.*)$(date +"%Y%m%d"):\$1$(date -d "+1day" +"%Y%m%d"):" *
```

But you can simplify you pattern like this:

```
rename "s#$(date +%Y%m%d)#$(date -d +1day +%Y%m%d)#" *
```

(this assumes `#` doesn't appear in the expansion of `date`).

Comment: thanks, I tried to escaping but never mind that I didn't do on `$1` :D And yes, I know that `(.*)` not requires here, but I should give one example that produce my question : )

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the Perl version of `rename`, one solution is to perform the date math with Perl.

```
rename 'use Time::Piece;use Time::Seconds;$t=localtime;$n=$t+ONE_DAY;$f=q{(.*)}.$t->strftime("%Y%m%d");s:$f:$1.$n->strftime("%Y%m%d"):e' *
```

Those modules should be in core for `perl` >= 5.10 unless your vendor has done strange things to the core install.